# Anaconda installation error winerror2 and also prompt is not worming

Tags: python, anaconda, failed-installation

I want to install anaconda but at the end of installation,got a error popup and and by ignoring it,only anaconda prompt is installed which is also not working.

I tried all possible solution like before installing, like:

Uninstall python, java 
Turn off window defender 
Remove jdk
Removing all previous anaconda and python files

Running anaconda as run as administrator

The error I get is:

> FilenotfoundError: [winerror 2] the system cannot find the file
>   specified

Installing in another directory or other drive
But nothing works...
Please help me with this..it completely stopped my learning process..!

Comment: FilenoyfoundError: [winerror 2] the system cannog find the file specified..